# Python задачка помогите решить

Tags: python

Условие задачи:
Введите с клавиатуры список с различными значениями (цифры, слова, символы). Необходимо проверить, есть ли в этом списке два слова подряд и вывести их на экран. Если таких пар нет, то выведите фразу “Мало слов!”.

Мой код:

```
list = []
def solution(list):
    result = []
    for i in list:
        if i.type == string:
            if (i+1).type == string:
                result.append(i)
    return result
    
solution(list)
```

Comment: Именно подряд чтобы были, или просто повторялись?

Comment: В каком формате вводятся данные? известно ли сколько входных данных? или входные данные, судя по примеру, не вводятся пользователем, а уже даны в списке? в вашем примере переменная `list`

Comment: список строк, цифр, символов подается в функцию, входных данных любое количество

Comment: А чем `слово` отличается от `не-слова`? С клавиатуры ведь вводятся в любом случае строки.

Comment: Я тоже думаю, что с клавиатуры в любом случае строка, но в задании написано что с клавиатуры подается список

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам простенькое рабочее решение

```
def solution(word_list):
    pairs = []
    length = len(word_list)
    for i in range(length):
        if i != length - 1 and word_list[i] == word_list[i + 1]:
            pairs.append((word_list[i], word_list[i + 1]))
    if pairs:
        print(pairs)
    else:
        print('“Мало слов!”')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Это задача с курса степика по фласку

Там вот какой пример давался в качестве теста

```
Sample Input:
Привет пока 12 когда 11 что где 

Sample Output:
Привет пока
что где
```

Вот моя программа, которая успешно прошла проверку знаний ( задача 1 )

```
def solution():
    x = input().split()
    word = ''
    littlewords = True
    for ii in x :
      if len( word ) > 0 and ii.isdigit() == False :    
        print( word + ' ' + ii )
        littlewords = False
      if ii.isdigit() == False :
        word = ii
      else :
        word = ''  
    if littlewords :
      print( 'Мало слов!' )      

solution()
```